# Nesting different types of lists in HTML

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I am trying to nest a list within a list in HTML, with the initial list being inline and the second list being below each other.

I have tried placing these lists with seperate  id's but both lists follow the same CSS as the first  see below.

```
      <div id= "deliveryListPage">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h8>Hello</h8>
            <br><br>
            <div id="firstList">
              <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>10</li>
                <li>11</li>
                <li>12</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h9><center>Can't see your postcode?</h9>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The div id "firstList" CSS styles are ignored and the deliveryListPage is the only one taken.

Comment: "both lists follow the same CSS" — What CSS?

Comment: `<h8>Hello</h8>` — Headings only go down 6 levels. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: `<h9><center>Can't see your postcode?</h9>
          </li>` — The center element is obsolete. Stop using it. We've had CSS for very nearly two and a half decades.

Comment: `<br><br>` — Line breaks are not a substitute for margin or padding

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed **inline CSS** to the firstList div.